# WCF endpoints information in the config file for different environments

Tags: web-services, wcf, web.config-transform

i wanted to know what is the best approach to save WCF endpoints information in the config file for different environments(DEV,TEST,PRE-PROD, PROD).

i am familiar with 1 way of doing this - 1. Maintain different config files(for each env) and deploy them accordingly.

Can someone please suggest the best way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the endpoint at runtime with endpointbehaviors. In this behaviors you can get the machinename for example. Depending on the machinename you could set yout endpointaddress for your endpoint, and then start the service.
Here is a link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730137%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**EDIT:**

So you write:

```
class CustomEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior{
 public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
  // get here the address and rewrite it dependig on the machinemane e.g.
  // remember to set the new address to the endpoint!

}

public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
{

}

public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
{

}

public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
{

}
}
```

And in the class where you start the service, you need to set the CustomEndpointBehavior to the serviceHost, like:

```
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the link. Create multiple configuration and then use pre build event to copy it.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx

In you have visual studio 2010 and above then it will be able to merge the config. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx